# C# How to drag Form from picturebox or panel?

Tags: c#, window, border, drag, wndproc

My problem is simple, I can't drag a window/form from picturebox or panel that is similar to custom toolbar/border.
Basicly you can drag only from background of the form, but not from any control.
Hope you understand my problem. If needed I can make video or pictures.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x84://Can move window if borders are off.
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if ((int)m.Result == 0x1)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)0x2;
                return;
            case 0x00A3: m.Result = IntPtr.Zero; return; //Double click won't zoom in.
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Drag it where? In the designer? While it's running? What does the posted code have to do with your problem?

Comment: @Brandon - I believe that he wants to be able to drag around a borderless form.  The code supplied will allow you to do that as long as you click on an empty area of the form itself.  But if you try to click and drag on a picturebox or panel or other control that is in the form, the code above won't work.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That's exactly what I ment. Any help?